# Android changelog history

Tags: android, version, changelog

I'm an intermediate android developer, mainly focused on 2.2.x versions. All my software is compatible with that version, but as android is evolving through new versions, I can't find a clear changelog history of development changes (new features introduced, which features are deprecated or removed and so on)

Can anyone suggest me any webpage, rss list or any pool of information where I can get detailed information about developer (no user-related, like change widgets place to new tab) related changes on every android version?

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.3.4.html look at this link. It has API changes for different versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking each API on [this page](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) gives you some details regarding new classes etc. After selecting an API you can then click on the "API Differences Report" link to see detailed changes from the previous version.